# Excel formula: If cell contains substring "this" AND does not contain substring "that"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a function in which a column contains one substring and does not contain another substring.

In the example bellow I would like my function to return 1 if my row contains "some project" AND DOES NOT CONTAIN "overhead".

```
row| example strings             | desired return value
0  |some project,other project   | 1
1  |some project                 | 1
2  |overhead                     | 0
3  |some project, overhead       | 0
4  |some project, other, boo     | 1
```

I was trying to formulate it first with exact strings such as:

```
=IF(AND((E3="some project"),NOT(E3="overhead")),1,0)
```

But this only gives correct results for row 1 and 2 because it only does exact mach for the string instead of matching on the substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is some kind of Substring function. I think `FIND` might work. Check out this page: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-find-function

**Your function would be like:
`=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("some project", E3))=FALSE,ISERROR(FIND("overhead",E3))),1,0)`**

**EDIT: Above function works after testing**

Tricky part here is that `FIND` returns the starting position of the string, and if it fails it returns `#VALUE`, which I believe you can catch with the `ISERROR()` function. This is in no way a beautiful solution. I would try to utilize the code behind and write this is VBA, as I am certain there is a proper `substring` function in VBA.

Answer (score 3):

If you can insert a little VBA code, then you can use a custom function like so:

```
=StrContains(E3, "some project", "overhead")
```

And this will return `True` if the value in E3 contains **both** of those substrings. This function relies mainly on VBA's [`Instr` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811.aspx), which

Function code:

```
Public Function StrContains(ByRef cl As Excel.Range, ParamArray strings() As Variant)
'Function returns TRUE if the range contains ALL of the passed substring items
' uses ParamArray to allow varying number of substring items
' Ex:
' =StrContains(A1, "something", "else", "foo")
'
Dim val$
Dim s
Dim i As Integer
Dim ret As Boolean
Dim length As Integer

length = UBound(strings) + 1
val = cl.Value2

For Each s In strings
    If InStr(1,val, s) <> 0 Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

ret = (i = length)
StrContains = ret
End Function
```

You could modify this relatively easily to be case-insensitive, or to accept partial matches optionally, etc. Here is what it looks like extended for both of those concepts:

```
=StrContains(E3, False, True, "some project", "overhead")
```

Function Code:

```
Public Function StrContains(ByRef cl As Excel.Range, MatchCase As Boolean, MatchAll as Boolean, ParamArray strings() As Variant)
'MatchAll is matching switch, use True to require ALL matching items, or False to allow for fewer.
'MatchCase is the Case-sensitive switch, use False to ignore case.
' uses ParamArray to allow varying number of substring items
' Ex:
' =StrContains(A1, "something", "else", "foo")
'
Dim val$
Dim s
Dim i As Integer
Dim ret As Boolean
Dim length As Integer

length = UBound(strings) + 1
val = cl.Value2

If Not MatchCase Then
    val = LCase(val)
    For i = lBound(strings) to UBound(strings)
        strings(i) = lcase(strings(i))
    Next
Next


For Each s In strings
    If InStr(val, s) <> 0 Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

ret = (i = IIF(MatchAll, length, 1))
StrContains = ret
End Function
```

Comment: The true solution here. While the excel functions may work, they are ugly and can be hard to understand.

Comment: thanks @wbrugato -- I was going to revise your post with something like this, but felt it better as a separate answer, since it's conceptually a bit different than using worksheet functions as per yours & the other answer above.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use the SEARCH function, like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("some project",B2)),NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("overhead",B2)))*1,0)
```

**Considerations**:

- [*SEARCH*](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) function: returns either a number or error (that's why I used ISNUMBER, you could actually have used [ISERROR](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) too). This function is **case insensitive**. For case sensitiveness you might just use [*FIND*](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628), in the previous formula woud be `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("some project",B2)),NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("overhead",B2)))*1,0)`
- [*ISNUMBER*](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) function: returns either FALSE or TRUE. I converted the result to 1 or 0 simply by multiplying TRUE or FALSE by 1.

Hope helps